# When and where should I drain the NSAutoreleasePool?

Tags: objective-c

I understand how to add items to an NSAutoreleasePool and how to drain the pool afterwards. But what's missing in my education is when and where this should be done.

Clearly just doing it in Main makes no sense because that's no different than never releasing the memory at all. But the documentation I've read so far hasn't offered me any other guidance on this.

Comment: Post some code and we can give you guidance. Where are you using an autoreleasepool? For what purpose? Etc

Comment: Did you really answer the question "Where should I do X?" with "Where are you doing X?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autorelease pool in `main` fulfills your applications's responsibility to Cocoa that an autorelease pool always be available.  This pool is drained at every cycle of the main event loop.

Further, each `NSThread` you create must have its own autorelease pool.

Beyond that, it is simply an issue of estimating how many autoreleased objects you are creating before the main autorelease pool drains.  You may also use Instruments to look at the peak memory footprint as further evidence of where an autorelease pool may be used.

Comment: Thanks. The whole pool thing still seems weird to me, but at least now I feel that I can trust it.

Answer (score 2):

It's useful to use an autorelease pool when you are allocating autoreleased objects in a loop, that will reduce the peak of memory consumption of the underlayer autorelease pool.

More info on autorelease pool in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Answer (score 1):

The only time you need to manually manage NSAutoreleasePool objects is when you are running in a thread. If the thread doesn't use much memory then drain at the beginning and drain at the end. Otherwise drain every so many loop iterations. How many iterations between draining the pool depends on the amount of memory you are using in the pool. The more often you drain the more efficient your memory usage is.

If you are doing this for something like a particle system with tens of thousands of particles, then you are better off not allocating & releasing memory all the time but instead allocate once and use a ring buffer or something similar.